# Can not stop Jboss7

Tags: java, jboss

I can not stop JBoss AS 7. This is how I do:

```
sudo sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect command=:shutdown
```

But console says:

> org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the
>   controller
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:284)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:250)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292)
>           at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455) Caused by: org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineException: The controller is not available
>   at localhost:9999
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:969)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:808)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:784)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:282)
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to
>   remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:947)
>           ... 11 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
>           at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:131)
>           at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:256)
>           at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.FutureManagementChannel$Establishing.getChannel(FutureManagementChannel.java:204)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(CLIModelControllerClient.java:160)
>           at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient$2.getChannel(CLIModelControllerClient.java:120)
>           at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:117)
>           at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:92)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:236)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:141)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:127)
>           ... 13 more

I was trying to do something like this:

```
sudo sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=192.168.100.25:9999 command=:shutdown
```

But still this error. Also this is my standalone:

```
 <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.100.25}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.100.25}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:192.168.100.25}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="5443"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-ejb">
            <remote-destination host="192.168.100.104" port="4447"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="192.168.100.25" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

This is `>ps -eaf | grep "jboss"`:

```
root       602     1  0 13:12 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root       655   602  0 13:12 pts/1    00:01:10 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root      5184     1  0 15:07 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root      5236  5184  6 15:07 pts/1    00:00:47 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root      5600     1  0 13:20 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root      5654  5600  0 13:20 pts/1    00:01:07 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     10975     1  0 13:29 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     11027 10975  0 13:29 pts/1    00:01:05 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    antonp   13335 27946  0 15:20 pts/1    00:00:00 grep jboss
    root     14235     1  0 13:34 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     14287 14235  1 13:34 pts/1    00:01:08 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     15298     1  0 Jun03 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     15350 15298  3 Jun03 ?        3-13:54:24 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     23573     1  0 13:50 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     23625 23573  1 13:50 pts/1    00:01:02 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     30201     1  0 13:08 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/bin/standalone.sh -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
    root     30253 30201  0 13:08 pts/1    00:01:06 /usr/lib/java/java-1.7.0/bin/java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/jboss-modules.jar -mp /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2 -Djboss.server.base.dir=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.ALLOW_HTTP_SEPARATORS_IN_V0=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

What's wrong? How can I stop Jboss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace the command is looking for the server at :`localhost:9999`.

```
java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999.
```

Try changing the port number to 8080 in:

```
controller=192.168.100.25:8080
```

Or,
Try the following.

To check if your JBOSS server is still running, run the following command.

```
ps -eaf | grep "jboss"
```

Check if the JBOSS instance is listed in the list of processes, if so take its process id and execute the kill command.

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: Look at the question again, pls. I've added some details.

Comment: Why are there so many instances running? Intended and binded to different ports or not closed ? Is this in production envirnoment?

Comment: I was trying to stop/start Jboss. That's why I suppose.

Comment: If this is not a production enviroment, then all these instances have been invoked but the command to stop them has failed. you can kill all of these and invoke a new one.

Comment: Execute a kill command like 'kill -9 5184', the second row is the PID.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill it with this script:

```
JBOSS_PID=`ps -ef | grep org.jboss.modules.Main | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`

if [ -n "$JBOSS_PID" ]; then
        kill $JBOSS_PID
else
    echo "No jboss server is running"
fi
```

Comment: "No jboss server is running"

Comment: Do a "ps -ef | grep jboss", depending on the version it can be that the main class is different.